# ASPxTreelist server side node selection doesnt work

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

i'm trying to select/unselect aspxtreelist nodes that meet the criteria.when user click  a row and it fires an event which handled by server side eventhandler.When i debug the code everthing ok.selection works but on the browser side selection remains same as before eventrised.

```
protected void grid_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        menutree.UnselectAll();
        EUserRole role = (EUserRole)grid.GetRow(grid.FocusedRowIndex);
        long roleguid = role.Guid;

        TreeListNodeIterator iterator = new TreeListNodeIterator(menutree.RootNode);
        while (iterator.GetNext() != null)
        {
            if ((long)iterator.Current["RoleGuid1"] == roleguid)
                iterator.Current.Selected = true;
        }

    }
```

How can solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

The cause of this issue is that your code is implemented during the grid's callback.  Since the callback response contains only information about the control which initiated it, your modifications done in the server side code do not appear in the client side.  A possible solution is to add both controls (ASPxGridView and ASPxTreeList) onto MS UpdatePanel and set the EnableCallbacks property of these controls(ASPxGridView and ASPxTreeList) to false.  In this case, the MS UpdatePanel will intercept postbacks and "convert" them to callbacks.  Also, both controls will be updated during these callbacks.

Comment: Thank you DevExpressTeam. i m new at asp.net controls.my poblem is solved.